# Return all non-error rows in Excel array

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing, match

I have a table (Table 1) with range D1:F20. In this table I have a series of data. Several rows in Table 1 have #N/A in cells of column D.
D1:F1 are headers.

I would like to create another table (Table 2) that collects all data in Table 1 except those rows that have #N/A. As I am thinking about it, I presume this will have to be an array formula that will loop through the rows in Table 1 and post to table 2 those without #N/A.

I have built the following formula:

```
{=INDEX($D$1:$F$20,MATCH(FALSE,ISERROR(D2),0))}
```

I have made it to be an array formula but it's not working. At the moment, it just returns Table 1 as it is, i.e., with all rows including those with #N/A.

How can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: couldn't you use the autofilter on table 1 column D to be all values except NA, then copy the visible cells to the other table?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, I'll have to use a formula as I cannot filter Table 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula and copy down to get just the non-error cells from your column D:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(D:D,SMALL(INDEX(NOT(ISERROR($D$2:$D$11))*ROW($D$2:$D$11),),SUMPRODUCT(--ISERROR($D$2:$D$11))+ROW(H1))),"")
```

Then you can do a VLOOKUP formula to get the contents from your columns D and E (assuming the contents of column D are unique).

If the contents of column D are not unique, copy this formula over to get the contents of E and F.

To increse formula performance, I recommend putting the Sumproduct portion in its own cell (this cell can be hidden, or even be put on a different worksheet and hide that worksheet), so that it is only calculated once and then referenced, instead of having each formula calculate it all over again.  This also lets you avoid the Iferror so that the formula doesn't have to be calculated when it runs out of valid values.  We'll say the Sumproduct formula gets put in cell Z1 as just this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISERROR($D$2:$D$11))
```

And then the main formula becomes this:

```
=IF(ROW(A1)>$Z$1,"",INDEX(D:D,SMALL(INDEX(NOT(ISERROR($D$2:$D$11))*ROW($D$2:$D$11),),$Z$1+ROW(A1))))
```